# Send/receive large data over BLE connection (BlueZ, d-bus, python)

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

Im currently trying to control my Raspberry PI via BLE and an app on my Android phone.
Im using BlueZ (v5.50) with d-bus and python on the PI side.
For my app im using Flutter with flutter_reactive_ble as bluetooth package.

I can connect and Read and Write small data to characteristics I defined.

However I have no idea how to Read/Write larger data from/to a characteristic.

I have read quite a bit online about BLE, but I'm entirely new to this subject and couldn't find any good tutorial on this topic.

Here's my characteristic which works for small data (strings):

```
from ..ble.characteristic import Characteristic
from ..ble.descriptor import Descriptor


class RequestModulesCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    REQUEST_MODULES_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = '82950D0C-CBF3-4370-AE30-ADC08875017E'

    def __init__(self, bus, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(
            self, bus,
            self.REQUEST_MODULES_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
            ['read', 'write'],
            service)
        self.add_descriptor(RequestModulesDescriptor(bus, 0, self))

    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        print(''.join([str(v) for v in value]))

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        return "Hello World".encode('utf-8')

class RequestModulesDescriptor(Descriptor):
    CUD_UUID = '2901'

    def __init__(self, bus, index, characteristic):
        Descriptor.__init__(
            self, bus, index,
            self.CUD_UUID,
            ['read'],
            characteristic)

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        desc = "Request available modules."

        return desc.encode('utf-8')
```

The imports and GATT Server is basically a copy of the BlueZ sample GATT Server which can be found here:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server

Interestingly if i write a long Lorem Ipsum text to my characteristic. Im using nRF Connect Android App for this. I recieve 600 Bytes of that message although my MTU (measured with `btmon | grep MTU`) is only 517 bytes.

The BlueZ docs have some offset parameter, but i can't wrap my head around that. Or do I have to use notify/indicate for something like this?

Can someone lead me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you saying that the Python GATT Server and nRF app is working together correctly?  While the Python GATT Server and the Flutter app is not? Sounds like an issue with the Flutter app. To write more than `ATT_MTU-3` bytes of data into a server’s characteristic value the client queue write operations, each of which includes an offset and the data itself, and then finally writing them all atomically with an execute write operation.

Comment: I don't think the nRF app even supports sending large data to a characteristic, i just tried with a long text and send that. Which truncated the text. Which is what i expected.
So to write large data your telling me to basically implement my own "fragmentation". I guess thats an acceptable solution, but i thought there might be some standardized way of doing it. What about reading a large characteristic from a server though? How would i implement that? I can't just push multiple "fragmented packets" to the client, can I?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to say that the long read or write should be taken care of automatically by the lower levels of BlueZ. I have a write characteristic that I have written to using chrome://bluetooth-internals/  in a Chrome browser on a Windows PC and it "just works". My test sends 1023 bytes/characters of "Lorem Ipsum" text and it just shows up on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Ok that's what i thought. I didn't knew about chrome://bluetooth-internals/ thanks for that :) I just tested again and it cuts the message after 600 bytes. But if this works for you i guess it's some problem with my python implementation.

Comment: How did you setup your GATT Server? Are you using the BlueZ sample or something else? I'm currently thinking about removing the bluetooth communication and just use plain old wifi, with a REST API on my raspberry.

Comment: The code I am using is from: https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero/blob/main/examples/ble_uart.py

Comment: I tested with your code and chrome://bluetooth-internals for me if i write to the characteristic only 514 bytes are received on the server side. Is there maybe some BlueZ configuration I'm missing? The library looks dope though!